# Use custom specific parsers for differents rss feeds

Tags: java, rss, feed, rome

I'm using ROME library to read RSS feeds with Java.

I'm in the case where I have multiples RSS feeds (all with 2.0 version) and each feed has its own structure and custom tags. I read in the official documentation that we can specify [a custom parser](https://rometools.github.io/rome/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5AndAboveTutorialsAndArticles/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEPluginsMechanism.html) when reading the feeds.

I have implemented a custom parser and specified this parser in a **rome.properties** and it works fine.

My goal as a next step is to specify a custom parser for each feed I'm reading to avoid having a **long and complex** parser.

But it appears in the documentation that custom parsers defined in the properties file are more intended to be used for different RSS versions rather than different XML structures.

> All the classes defined in this property have to implement the com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedParser interface. Parser instances must be thread-safe. The return value of the getType() method is used as the primary key. If more than one parser returns the same type, the latter one prevails.

The `getType()` method here points out to the *rss version*

I need to know if there is a way (or not) to specify with ROME different custom parsers for different feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Made this work by defining a different feed type for each of my custom parser, and overriding `isMyType` so that it checks the source link or title of the RSS feed.

```
public class FooParser extends RSS20Parser {
  
   public FooParser() { super("foo_rss_2.0"); }

   @Override
   public boolean isMyType(Document document) {
      return super.isMyType(document) && isFoo(document);
   }

}
```

Then, you can define a Converter for that feed type.

```
public class FooConverter extends ConverterForRSS20 {
   public FooConverter() { super("foo_rss_2.0"); }
}
```

You need to register both in `rome.properties`

```
WireFeedParser.classes=FooParser
Converter.classes=FooConverter
```

Somehow I also had re-order how the plugins are loaded by `rome`. I found out that I can do this by re-adding `RSS20Parser` into the "extra plugin" file.

```
WireFeedParser.classes=FooParser \
  com.rometools.rome.io.impl.RSS20Parser
Converter.classes=FooConverter \
  com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS20
```

If you don't do this, `RSS20Parser` will be used for all your RSS 2.0 feeds.